# Proper vocabulary for Test Case

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I am sorry if this doesn't pertain to a specific programming work but it is closely related to writing testing cases.
I am in the process of translating IT test cases written in Japanese and I was wondering what are the English equivalent words to describe the following test scenarios.

I can write the descriptions of each types of test cases.
If I translate them directly, they use the words "Normal" "Semi-normal" "Abnormal"
to describe the kind of test cases they write.

Normal : this indicates cases that test for operations that occurs during daily business transactions

Semi-normal: indicates cases that test for operations that do not occur during business transactions but can possibly occur ex) input overflow

Abnormal: cases that test for operations that can only occur if something "abnormal" is done or happens ex) time out due to network being down, disk write overflow due to full capacity

Are there words to describe the 3 terms above?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Those sound pretty good. I've seen "expected behavior" as a synonym for your "normal", but "abnormal" seems to be the common term as you've used it (even more than just "unexpected"). Are you looking for something like an industry standard?

Comment: For all of your Japanese translation needs there is http://japanese.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The term we use at my organization for the first case would be "Happy path", Curiously, we don't use "unhappy path" for any of those other situations.

Answer (score 0):

On a previous team, we used the notion of classing tests by priorities. Something like Priority 0 where tests that would test base functionality; these are the common tests that have to work as they are the 'happy path' (like [TokenMacGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326610/proper-vocabulary-for-test-case/6326631#6326631) mentioned) or would address the most important set of inputs or features.  Priority 1 cases were important, but tested things outside of normal usage (most of the negative tests, and positive tests to ensure a relative degree of robustness). The Priority 2 cases would address boundary conditions, "abnormal" inputs.  Finally, there are other classes of testing we called "Stress testing" to push the capacity of the system and test environmental conditions, such as loss of network, disk issues, memory contention, CPU load, etc.  Check out [How We Test at Microsoft](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624259) for a good overview of some of these terms and test categories.